# 'dotnet test' is not finding nunit tests in gitlab-runner pipeline

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, gitlab-ci-runner, dotnet-test

I have a solution with a `NUnit` testproject (`Foo.Test`).

```
+-- src
|   +-- Foo.Gui
|   +-- Foo.Test
```

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="TestResults\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="TestResults\**" />
    <None Remove="TestResults\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GitVersionTask" Version="5.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Foo.Gui\Foo.Gui.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The following call is used for testing:

`dotnet test --no-build -c Release -v n src\%TESTPROJECT%\%TESTPROJECT%.csproj --logger "trx;LogFileName=testreport.trx"`

**If I run it local, everything is working as expected:**

[image]

**The same call on build server is not finding any test:**

[image]

## gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
test:solution:
    stage: test
    script:
        - dotnet test --no-build -c Release -v n src\$env:TESTPROJECT\$env:TESTPROJECT.csproj --logger "trx;LogFileName=testreport.trx"
    after_script:
        - trx2junit src\$env:TESTPROJECT\Testresults\testreport.trx 
    artifacts:
        reports:
            junit: src\$env:TESTPROJECT\Testresults\testreport.xml
```

Someone got a hint what can be wrong? The Testproject (Foo.Test.dll) is available and present in the build artifacts.

Comment: Is the NUnit3 adapter present in the output directory?

Comment: Yes it is. Actually I think I foung the answer. I had to add an additional `dotnet restore` command on the build pipeline before testing, to restore the `project.assets.json`. Then everything works as expected 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add an additional `dotnet restore` command on the build pipeline before testing, to restore the `project.assets.json`. Now everything is working as expected

```
test:solution:
    stage: test
    script:
        - dotnet restore src
        - dotnet test --no-build -c Release -v n src\$env:TESTPROJECT\$env:TESTPROJECT.csproj --logger "trx;LogFileName=testreport.trx"
    after_script:
        - trx2junit src\$env:TESTPROJECT\Testresults\testreport.trx 
    artifacts:
        reports:
            junit: src\$env:TESTPROJECT\Testresults\testreport.xml
```

Comment: Any idea why? I feel like this is a bug with dotnet test. I had GitLab add both the bin and obj folders of both my project and test project (so it includes project.assets.json of both) to the artifacts and _still_ had to do a dotnet restore before the tests could be discovered.

Comment: I honestly did not investigate the problem further. Now that this simple solution always works, the problem was solved for me.

Comment: I suspect to make sure the unit test adapter is available. You can also install test adapters globally to ensure they're always available.

Comment: @jessehouwing Could you tell us more about how to install the adapter globally?

Comment: You can store the test adapter anywhere and then pass the path to your test adapters to `dotnet test`. Add: `"-p:VSTestTestAdapterPath=/path/to/test adapters/"`, the path you pass in will be searched recursively.