# dotnet restore: exclude project

Tags: .net, .net-core, wix

I have a `project solution` where I also got a `wix` project. Actually `wix` is not supported by `dotnet`. On my build pipeline I have to run `dotnet restore` for the next `stage`.

But because of the `wix` project, I always get the following error:

> D:\GitlabRunnerService\builds\fc40b836\0\customers\foo\foo-zls\src\foo.zls.setup.common\foo.zls.setup.common.wixproj(34,5): error : The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Is there any solution **how to exlude projects from the `dotnet restore` command?**

---

## gitlab-ci.yml

```
test:Common:
    stage: test
    script:
        - dotnet restore src
        - dotnet test --no-build -c Release -v n src\$env:TESTPROJECT\$env:TESTPROJECT.csproj --logger "trx;LogFileName=testreport.trx"
    after_script:
        - trx2junit src\$env:TESTPROJECT\Testresults\testreport.trx 
    artifacts:
        reports:
            junit: src\$env:TESTPROJECT\Testresults\testreport.xml
    tags:
        - dotnet-ps
```

In the `Release` configuration, the `wix` project is already excluded.

Comment: Have you tried to skip this project from build in solution properties?

Comment: Right click project in solution view => Unload project => Build?

Comment: I have added some more informations

Answer (score 2):

Instead of restoring the complete solution, I only restore the specific project(s). So after changing the restore command to `dotnet restore src\$env:TESTPROJECT\$env:TESTPROJECT.csproj` everything works as expected!`

---

OffTopic:

I need the `dotnet restore` command to find all `nunit tests` in buid pipeline..

['dotnet test' is not finding nunit tests in gitlab-runner pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993042/dotnet-test-is-not-finding-nunit-tests-in-gitlab-runner-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Hi All I am also facing same issue however I manage to resolve it. After Comparing Project Dependency folder name case i Found that, while taking project reference in .net core, some character in path become upper case as shown in below.

XX.XXXXX.Aws.XX - Correct one
XX.XXXXX.AWS.XX - Auto convert and unable to read